# Push images to server from a specific folders via discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-os

I have some problems with my discord bot, I'll try to explain as much as I can.
So i have a bot's folder, which contains a bot itself, and a folder named `commands`, basically it's where my cogs are stored, and inside the folder `commands` there is a folder named `images`, in which i saved images for my bot to pick randomly. the problem is that i couldn't manage to tell the bot to take images from that specific folder, and instead it only works if i put images directly into bot's folder (the first folder). I've tried many things, such as:

```
@commands.command()
    async def randomimage(self, ctx):
       for list os.listdir(./commands/images/):
        list = (images here)
        await ctx.send('take this', file=discord.File(random.choice(list)))
```

but that didn't help either, i can just put /commands/images/(image) to every image but the list is huge and i don't want to write path to every image there.

bot:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import os

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

#this script types "Connected!" in terminal if nothing has gone wrong    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Connected!')        

for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
   if filename.endswith('.py'):
      bot.load_extension(f'commands.{filename[:-3]}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

the whole command:

```
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class randomimage(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def randomimage(self, ctx):
       #waiting for suggestion on this line
        list = (image list)
        await ctx.send('take this', file=discord.File(random.choice(list)))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(randomimage(client))
```

I'm kind of noob here so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out. Apparently answer was as easy as changing a directory, literally

I've used `os.chdir('./commands/images')` and it worked.

Edit: Apparently I was wrong and that didn't work either
Update: apparently os.chdir works, but I have to specify the full path, like `/home/user/discordbot/commands/images`, so yes, that works